# How to create a elliptical CGPathRef?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-graphics, sprite-kit, cgpath

I am new to core graphic in cocoa.
I have a picture of a egg and I am using Sprite kit to simulation physics of free falling of an egg.
I need to set the egg's physicsBody property.
How to create an elliptical CGPathRef for the purpose?

For an egg shape path, I have to create an half of circle with half of oval. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow me to point you to the reference documentation of CGPath, where you will find [CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect).

Comment: Thank you for you answer.For an egg shape path, I have to create an half of circle with half of oval. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I just ran into this problem in an app that I was writing to create some graphics assets.

```
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 10, 95);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, (5 + SIZE) * 1.5, 95 - SIZE * 1 / 3);

CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.0);
CGPathAddArc(path, &t, SIZE + 5, 95 - SIZE * 4 / 3, SIZE, M_PI / 2, -M_PI * 5 / 4, YES);
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
```

TL;DR

You have to use CGAffineTransform in order to get an arc of an ellipse.